# Убрать горизонтальный скролл

Tags: html, css

Учусь верстать макет, графика выходит за пределы 1000px.
Желательно сделать так, что бы на мониторе с разрешением экрана 1024x768px не появлялся горизонатальный скролл, а то, что не влезло, просто оставалось за пределами браузера.
Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Добавляем к блоку в котором нужно убрать скролл стиль (в CSS или напрямую)

```
overflow:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;  /*для вертикального*/
overflow-x:hidden;  /*для горизонтального*/
<body style='overflow-x:hidden;'>
```

- [overflow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)
- [overflow x](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow-x)
- [overflow y](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow-y)

Comment: @UndReim вместо использования тегов pre чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 8):

Всё очень просто пишем:

```
html{

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

  body
  {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#wrapper { width: 980px; overflow: show; }
```

Обычно такого хватает. #`wrapper` - обертка всего сайта, обычно идет следом за `body`

Comment: _`overflow: show`_ - что?

Answer (score 1):

А ещё для IE<8 чтобы убрать прокрутку ничего кроме:

```
<body scroll="no">
```

не помжет!

Answer (score 0):

контейнеру, в который не влазит контент добавить свойство overflow:hidden; это скроет непомещающиеся части.

Answer (score -1):

если я правильно понял, то одно из свойств CSS вам должно помочь [position: absolute](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position). А также можно поиграться вот с этими свойствами [max-width](http://htmlbook.ru/css/max-width) и [min-width](http://htmlbook.ru/css/min-width). Можно еще попробовать обернуть картинку в DIV и этому же DIV`у задать background, и указать размеры картинки которая задана фоном.